# Opening an .R files EDIT: gzip files saved with .R extension. Is there any other way to access them?

Tags: r

I have a number of R files with an `.R` extension. I've tried various ways to see what is inside these file, including Xcode, vim, etc.

What I find is utterly indecipherable. For example, it looks like this `Lçæ§o‡dµ’Ò6ÇìùëﬁFŒÀ±y2Â8á∫˝É`, but pages of it.

Is it safe to say that these files are fundamentally corrupt? Or should I be using R to open these files to see what's actually in them?

EDIT: I've never worked with a file like this. After using `load()` in R, how would I read the data? I have used

```
> data <- load("~/filename.RData")
> data
```

The output is `[1] "filename"`.

EDIT2: It appears these are gzip files saved with an `.R` extension. I can using `load()` to read the data into `R`. Is there any other way I can access these data files?

Comment: `.R` files are plain-text files; so, without any further information, I'd say the files are indeed corrupted

Comment: I would try renaming them with an .rdta extension and see whether they can be read with load().

Comment: @BondedDust Shouldn't the extension be `.RData`?

Comment: Specific range of extensions that succeed will depend on the setup of your R installation. That should work as well.

Comment: Did you just happen upon these files or did someone give them to you as files related to the R stats program? It's possible that some program other than R also has the convention of using that file extension.

Comment: @Frank It's part of the R stats program. All files were sent together. The R code files work. The `.R` files are garbage.

Comment: http://www.checkfiletype.com/

Comment: @BondedDust Well, it does "load()" with the new extension but I'm not sure whether it's being read. What do you suggest?

Comment: Are you under linux? If so, you could try "file your-file.R" on the terminal. This will show you if it's a "UTF-8 Unicode text" or anything.

Comment: If you didn't get an error when you ran `load()` on it, then you probably have new data-objects in your work-space. You can see all you objects with `ls()`.

Comment: @Rodrigo "file your-file.R" returns "your-file.R: gzip compressed data, from Unix"

Comment: .R should be plain text? Rename it to the proper extension (.gzip?) and try to unzip it.

Comment: @Rodrigo Good idea. I renamed the file `fname.R` in the terminal with `cp fname.R fname.gzip`. Unzipping the file (either by clicking it or using `gunzip fname.gzip` outputs nothing usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"filename" is now loaded and it is stored in an object of the same name. You should be able to see what it is inside by running:

```
filename
```

Comment: They were compressed data files. I am an idiot. Thanks for the help!